# SSL/TLS with Eclipse Paho JavaScript Client

Tags: ssl, nginx, websocket, mosquitto

I've got a JavaScript-based WebApp that includes the Eclipse Paho client.

The WebApp is stored and executed on an NGINX webserver. 
On the same Server where the webserver is installed, the MQTT broker mosquitto is running. I've defined port 8884 as listener port for secured connections.

Running mosquitto_sub (simple C client) with --cafile and -p 8884 works fine!

Now I want to secure the WebApp using SSL by passing mqttOptions = { useSSL: true } in my MQTT client implementation.

I can see that the app is trying to establish an connection to wss://ip instead of ws://ip. But the server responds with a connection refused which is totally clear because I did not configure anything on the webserver as I do not have a clue how to manage this. Will the wss connection be 'mapped' to a https or something? Do I need a websocket proxy in NGINX? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: sorry, the error is not "connection refused" but "WebSocket connection to 'wss://ip' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled"

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the same port for raw MQTT and MQTT over websockets with mosquitto, you need to create 2 separate listeners.

The fact that you can connect with mosquitto_sub implies you have only set up a listener with the raw MQTT.

e.g.

```
listener 8883

listener 8884
protocol websockets
```

This will create a native MQTT listener on 8883 and a MQTT over websockets on port 8884

Answer (score 1):

I did so. Here is the mosquitto conf entry:

```
listener 8884 127.0.0.1
protocol websockets
cafile /path/to/ca.crt
certfile /path/to/certfile.crt
keyfile /path/to/keyfile.key
require_certificate false
```

and so the app is trying to connect to myip:8884

Comment: Are you trying to connect from the same machine or a different one? You have bound it to 127.0.0.1 (localhost) so clients connecting from other machines will not be able to. (also you should use comments to reply to answers not a new answer)

Comment: But the websocket client (the browser) is not on the same machine? (and you can edit the original question to add clarification if needed)

Comment: ah ok websocket client is somewhere else... I removed the binding 127.0.0.1 Thanks so far! But that's not the cause of my connection handshake cancellation I guess.